# How to display list categories in wordpress integration magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, integration, categories, fishpig

Can help somebody. I spent several hours to find solution but without results
I tried to display the list of categories on homepage wordpress blog thru following code

```
<?php $category = Mage::registry('wordpress_category') ?>
<?php if ($category): ?>
<?php echo $category->getId() ?>: <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But the method

```
Mage::registry('wordpress_category')
```

always return null. 
I found that, i should probably be using the Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Category_View. But i dont know where i should put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will retrieve the current category when viewing a category page in your blog:

```
<?php Mage::registry('wordpress_category') ?>
```

This is not what you need. To view a list of categories, you could create a custom collection using the following:

```
<?php $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_category_collection') ?>
```

A better way would be to use the category widget block:

```
<block type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_categories" name="wp.categories" template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml" />
```

You can create this in PHP using the following code:

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')
    ->createBlock('wordpress/sidebar_widget_categories')
    ->setTemplate('wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml')
    ->toHtml() ?>
```

The above code uses the default template, however, feel free to use your own custom template.

Comment: how to do this in magento 2?